# Why is dynamically created ul not rendering any HTML?

Tags: jquery

Why is it that, whichever of the following I use to create a new `<ul>` element, the HTML is empty:

```
var complaintsList = $('<ul/>', { id : 'myId' });
```

or

```
var complaintsList = $("<ul id='myId'></ul>");

alert($(complaintsList).html());
```

When I add `<li>` elements to the list and output the HTML, only the HTML of the `<li>` elements is displayed.

Can someone explain what I'm doing wrong please?

Comment: Show how you're outputting the HTML.

Comment: `alert(complaintsList[0].outerHTML);` works

Comment: `outerHTML` function for jQuery: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2419749/get-selected-elements-outer-html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the console:

```
var complaintsList = $('<ul/>', { id : 'myId' });

complaintsList
[
<ul id=​"myId">​</ul>​
]

complaintsList.html()
""

complaintsList.append("<li>")
[
<ul id=​"myId">​
<li>​</li>​
</ul>​
]

complaintsList.html()
"<li></li>"
```

It works as expected. The html of the `ul` is blank because there is nothing in it. Once you add the `li`, there is a list item in it.

[`.html()`](http://api.jquery.com/html/) only gives you the HTML of the **contents** of the element. So when you have nothing in the element, the HTML will be an empty string. If you need to get the `outerHTML` of the element, you can use the [jQuery outerHTML plugin](http://darlesson.com/jquery/outerhtml/).

Comment: This is so weird - even after populating the list with li elements, and dumping the HTML to console.log, the ul element is not part of the HTML?

Comment: No, it'll only give you the HTML of the contents of the element, not including the element.

Comment: Yup I see I've got the wrong idea here - I've asked a very silly question indeed :) Thanks guys for putting me straight - been one of those days!

Answer (score 0):

http://api.jquery.com/html/ says:

> "Get the HTML contents of the first element in the set of matched
>   elements."

`.html()` returns only the internal contents of the element, but not the element itself.

See `innerHTML` vs `outerHTML`, `.html()` is similar to the  `.innerHTML` property.

Answer (score 0):

> Why is it that, whichever of the following I use to create a new 
>   element, the HTML is empty

Because the `html` method returns the HTML code of the elements inside the (first) element in the jQuery object.

> Can someone explain what I'm doing wrong please?

You have assumed that the `html` method also includes the HTML code of the element in the jQuery object.

---

Side note: The variable `complaintsList` already contains a jQuery object, so you don't have to wrap it in another jQuery object to use jQuery methods on it:

```
alert(complaintsList.html());
```